# Date time converted to smalldatetime after import

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, import, ssms

I imported all the tables in my database to another database in a remote server using SSMS. I could find that none of the constraints were imported to the new table. Even the primary key wasn't set in the imported table. And all the `datetime` were converted to `smalldatetime` . What is the reason that the table was not copied exactly as it was during the import?  Would there be any issues while running the program with the imported database. My code works perfect with `datetime`. Will I have to change my code to get it working to avoid any future issues in the code? As of now it is working with a small test.

Table was copied from Local Database(Sql Server) to SQLServer Express.

**Adding image based on comments**

[image: Initial Database design]

[image: Database design after import]

Comment: "*I imported all the tables in my database to another database*" - how exactly you've done this? By restoring backup, by some script, any othe option?

Comment: using SSMS. Uodated question. I added the tag. but missed to add it in the question. Using the import wizard.

Comment: did you use sql server integration services? or did you just script out everything in a query editor and executed it on the new server? a screenshot or 2 of the UI you are using would be nice. :D

Comment: I only used the import wizard to copy the database. I did no scripting.. Did not change anything in the wizard. Screenshot of the SSMS? or import wizard? I really did not understand what you are looking for

Comment: what is wrong with the question to be downvoted??

Comment: The reason why it is downvoted is becasue it is very vague and doesn't show much attempt at trying to figure out what is wrong. One thing you could try doing is pull the table into a csv file and then save and load it into the table as a flat file then you can change the datatype of that column to Date when you pull it in to the other loaction. The wizard allows you to select the data type when usinf a flat file.

Comment: I could not try anything to understand why it was converted. But only that i could do was to change all the smalldatetime to datetime manually in d table design. I was asking for the reason why this is happening while importing the table.

Comment: @WesPalmer : Even when I do it the way I did i chad an option to change the mapping. But it would have been a real overhead as i will have to edit more than 100 tables. And none of the foreign keys and primary key constraints were imported.

Comment: The best way to brign everything over correctly then may be to take a backup of the DB and restore it then you would have to write some queries to make everything the way you need it to be. The backup will keep all the constraints and everything. Other than that I am not sure of a good way to do it. Can you update your question with what the date column looks like befre and after? And what the column definition is before and after as well if you can get it. That would help give a better answer possibly.

Comment: @WesPalmer :  Added the images of my table design. Sorry for the late response :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the import/export utility it will guess the best data type which is why it is sayig smalll date time. Here is what I would do. Go to the destination table and drop the table. Then right-click on the source table and select Scirpt Table As... --> CREATE To --> New Query Editor Window. Then run the query it generates on the destination database. Then after you have a exact copy of the schema import the data into it this way it should be loaded in as the original DATETIME datatype.

Note: If you don't want to drop the other table thats fine just be sure to change the name of the table before you run the create table statement. Other then this I am not sure what to do. I hope this helps you,